# Where are all the Population III galaxies?

Tags: big-bang, galaxies, stellar-population

We can now see back to 400 million years after the Big Bang.  Yet we still haven't seen any Population III galaxies.  Why is this?  How do metal-rich galaxies evolve in just 400 million years?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the highest redshift galaxy confirmed is at $z=11.1$, corresponding to a mere 400 million years after the big bang ([Oesch et al. 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.00461)). This galaxy, and a few others like it, were discovered because of their extremely red colours and a sharp step in their spectral energy distribution in the near-infrared, known as the [Lyman break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyman-break_galaxy). Photons shortward of the Lyman limit in the rest frame of the galaxy (91.2 nm) are heavily absorbed by neutral hydrogen in that galaxy. This absorption edge is then redshifted by a factor $1+z$ in the observed spectral energy distribution. However, in the early universe, prior to the main epoch of reionisation at $z \sim 6$, much of the intergalactic medium is also in the form of neutral hydrogen, and the presence of this, at a range of redshifts between $6<z<11$ means that the Lyman series effectively absorbs everything shortward of the Lyman alpha line at a rest wavelength of 121.6 nm.

The discoveries are confirmed with long spectroscopic exposures in the near infrared, to establish the reality of the Lyman break, measure its wavelength and hence determine the redshift of the galaxy. The only thing that is detectable is a (weak) continuum - no spectral emission or absorption lines. So there is no information about the metallicity of the galaxy and therefore one cannot call it a population III galaxy.

It could be that subsequent measurements, perhaps by JWST, were to find little evidence for metals in such galaxies. Indeed, there has been some evidence for extremely metal-poor galaxies ([Sobral et al. 2015](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.01734)) at redshifts of $z \sim 7$ (about 800 million years after the big bang). They detect no emission lines except Lyman alpha and ionised helium, but even here, Sobral et al. suggest that the spectra are best described as a mixture of population III and more chemically evolved populations.

It would not be surprising to find a metal-enriched interstellar medium and/or stars with metals after only a few hundred million years. Some population III stars are expected to be very massive (100-1000$M_{\odot}$), with lifetimes of only a few million years before they explode in some type of supernova (still theoretically uncertain). The cycle of enrichment will thus begin after a galaxy has formed in only a fraction of the age of the universe at that time. How effective that is will depend on all sorts of uncertain factor like what the masses of population III stars are, what the yields are from their supernovae, how important mass loss is from population III stars and how effective are the mixing processes that churn the gas from which new stars are formed. Either way, if a galaxy is discovered on the basis of its Lyman alpha or Lyman continuum emission it is likely to be dominated by the light from hot, young, very massive stars that have recently formed and exhibit the metallicity of the material of the interstellar medium at that time, and not longer-lived, somewhat lower mass stars that may well have zero/little metallicity.

Comment: At recombination, the density of energy varied only 1 part in 100,000.  Every single part of the galaxy, for all intents and purposes, pulled with equal weight on every other part.  I don't have a supercomputer handy so it's difficult for me to imagine a scenario where that kind of homogeneity can create enough contrast for a 1,000 solar mass star in just 100 million years.  I know they wave their hands and say "Dark Matter" did it, but DM doesn't clump that well in the present-day universe.  How did it work back then?

Comment: @DonaldRoyAirey That seems to be a differrent question to the one you've asked. Dark matter is indeed what caused the first galaxies to form, at most, 400 million years after the BB. You also seem misled about the recombination epoch, which was 400 *thousand* years after the BB!

Comment: Jefferies -  Thanks for that, I've modified the question accordingly.  I greatly appreciate the detail you've provided, but I don't believe it is a different question.  I would like to know how metal rich galaxies can evolve in just 400 million years when they start out with a perturbation of 1 part in 100,000.  That means an entire galaxy had to form from a homogenous gas in less time than it took our solar system to evolve from the detritus of a Type II star.

Comment: @DonaldRoyAirey Where do you get the latter statement from,? It isn't true. Our Sun formed from a gas cloud in about a million years.

Comment: Probably a BBC documentary.  The gas collected and it took about 50 million years to start a fusion reaction.  I've not found anything on the internet to suggest it formed in a million years, but I'll take your word for it.  My point is that our sun was already in a highly organized part of the universe.  400 years after the BB, the universe was, for all intents and purposes, uniform.

Comment: The Sun took about 1 million years to form and 10 million years to begin fusion. But it is a small star. A 20+solar mass star has completed its lifecycle in this time.

Comment: I no longer understand your question. Observations show that galaxies exist 400 million yearsafter the BB. We have no idea how metal rich they are. Cosmological simulations show that galaxies/stars can form this rapidly, but only because of dark matter.